# How can I make an Apple WatchOS 6 independent app auto-launch on watch startup

Tags: apple-watch, launch, watchos

On the new watchOS 6 I am building a watch app that is independent and I want it to auto-launch when the watch turns on. Are there specific developer permissions I need to allow this OR can I make the app a designated type (e.g. workout app, health app) OR any other way anyone knows to do this.

Right now I have the app running but the user has to tap a complication to turn the app on which they only remember to do sometimes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, the user has to launch the app themselves.